# DNN9 svg file upload

Tags: svg, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Is anyone familiar with DNN 9 platform here? If so could someone direct me how to upload an svg file to the server. In older version of DNN(8,7 etc) there was a setting in the Host List settings where you could enable the file type, however in DNN these pages have been removed from the user interface.

The following command has been run in  SSMS:

INSERT INTO Lists (ListName, Value, Text, DefinitionID, SystemList)

VALUES ('ImageTypes', 'svg', 'Scalable Vector Graphics', '-1', 'True');

This created a new line in the database, however when I try to upload a svg file it still show wrong format (The Allowed Filetypes are: "bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png").

Can someone direct me perhaps where can the svg file type be enabled?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The option to add file types is still there. It has been moved and has a different name. Go to:

```
Settings > Security > More
```

There is a tab there called `More Security settings`. There you will find the `Allowable File Extensions`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I have got the svg listed there..any other ideas.. webconfig or MIME type? I had a look in webconfig and can not see anything related to this. Could be something on server side still blocking it?

Comment: Could be, however unlikely. svg has worked for me on more that 1 installation on different servers without any changes to config or IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Some DNN sites allow users to upload certain files to their sites. A malicious can upload an SVG file which can contain some malicious code to steal some users’ sensitive data (cookies, etc.)

Comment: Verion 9.20 or later will not accept SVG files for download.